# core graphics create an oval border with curves

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I need some help to create  borders like in the pic below.  [image: pic]

how can I create borders like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some clues

1. Draw two ellipse with same center,one large A and other small B
2. Get the points at regular intervals on an  ellipse
3. These points will be the starting and ending point and draw small arc ,Mathematically calculate the values and implement it

[This is an excellent tutorial to help you drawing arcs and some basic calculation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33193/core-graphics-tutorial-arcs-and-paths)

Comment: @LithuTV any chance to throw in a simple eg?

Comment: @aVC Edited the answer,added the link

Comment: @LithuTV ok will try that. Any thoughts on what would be the best way to implement the tail part? I would like it to be repositionable by touch/dragging the tip

Comment: @aVC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763695/given-a-cgpath-how-to-make-it-curve/16782469#16782469

Comment: @PeterHosey thanks for the link. I still have the question, whether the tail is better to be a seperate entity (like a triangle) or can it be part of the ellipse that forms the speech bubble?

Comment: @aVC: Do it separately, the same way comic artists do it on paper. Stroke first, then fill, so that the fill obliterates any stroke-lines that get caught in the intersection.

Comment: @LithuT.V I am at a loss about finding the equidistant points on the ellipse. If you got a handle on that, please do share. :) I hv been reading all day  without much avail.