# Animate a view along just a part of a path in iOS

Tags: ios, core-animation, uibezierpath, cgpath

I have a long path and I want to animate a view along just a part of it. I need a way to get just a part of this path which I calculate as a portion of it.

For example, with CAShapeLayer you can get a portion of it with strokeStart and strokeEnd and then draw just the part you are interested in.
I'd like to do the same with a path and then animate a view just along the portion I choose.

My path is long, but is not divided in equal subpaths, so I can't use the subpaths to get the portion I need.

Any idea?
Any help would be really appreciated;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the accepted answer here: [Place images along a bezier path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112497/place-images-along-a-bezier-path)

Once you have found points in the path you can make many subpaths of the same length and move animations along these