# Is it possible to align views on a path perimeter?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to achieve the following by code:

[image]

Based on a circular path or arc, I need to place other views evenly around the perimeter.

Is this possible without hardcoding the frames? If so, how?
In addition to that, can I make a view to follow a path ? if so, how?

Update:
I found this answer helpful, but it seems to use a lot of code though...
[Place images along a bezier path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112497/place-images-along-a-bezier-path)

Comment: Yes and yes, you can do both.

Comment: Please don't include unnecessary or false tags. When you have said "ios" you have implied "iphone" and "cocoa". This has nothing to do with "xcode". I have left "objective-c", however, because it indicates what language you'd like code to be in.

Comment: Got it, thanks. BTW, I'm modifying my question, the idea is to have an answer of how to do it, not intended to be a Y/N question

Comment: I've explained how to do it and I've added a screenshot to show that it works.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy. A view is a layer.

A layer is *positioned* by its anchor point. So place the layer's anchor point at the center of the circular path, and define the anchor point at a sufficient size to move the layer away from the center to lie on the desired radius.

Moreover, a layer is *rotated* around around its anchor point, so now just apply a rotation transform in an increment of nths of a circle, where, n is the number of views.

As you can see, I can easily draw your sub-circles evenly spaced out, given any number of desired sub-circles:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks you! ... but I need the center of the views to follow a path just in case it is deformed into a elipse or other shapes.

Comment: You never said that in your question, though. I answered the question you asked. I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: That's true, sorry for taking a minute of your time. BTW, there's no need to be rude man.