# iOS : bow ends thinner than the center

Tags: ios, curve

I'm drawing a curve between two points with a `centerPoint`, and I would like to have the bow ends thinner than the `center` part. I mean, I want different `setLineWidth` for the ends. Any idea?

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGPoint p=CGPointMake(posXAbsolutaComienza, posYAbsolutaComienza);
[path moveToPoint:p];
CGPoint p2=CGPointMake(posXAbsolutaAcaba, posYAbsolutaAcaba);
CGPoint centerPoint=CGPointMake(posXAbsolutaIntermedio, posYAbsolutaIntermedio);
[path setLineWidth:grosorLinea]; 
[path addQuadCurveToPoint:p2 controlPoint:centerPoint];
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
[path stroke];
```

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26556758/608157) will be helpful for you.

Comment: Do you want the lines to end at a point or just be thinner?